# Generalization of Gauss' mean value theorem

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

**EDIT:** How to get this, if it is possible to get it:
$$f^{(n)}(z_o)=\frac{n!}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}f(e^{i\theta}+z_o)(e^{ni\theta})^{-1}\ d\theta$$

---

I was reading [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/723843/80965) question, and wanted to write it down to also find Cauchy's differentiation formula. This is what I have so far:

We have Cauchy's formula: 
$$f(z_o)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\Gamma \frac{f(z)}{z-z_o}dz$$
then we consider $\gamma:[0,2\pi]\to\Bbb C$ as $\theta\mapsto re^{i\theta}+z_o$, which is circle with center in $z_o$ and radius $r>0$ such that it is entirely contained in the geometric interior of $\Gamma$. We get:
$$f(\gamma(\theta))=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{f(\gamma(\theta))}{\gamma(\theta)-z_o}\gamma'(\theta)\ d\theta \\
=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{f(re^{i\theta}+z_o)}{re^{i\theta}}(ire^{i\theta})\ d\theta \\ 
=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} f(re^{i\theta}+z_o)\ d\theta$$
**(a)**: Is this what it says in the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/723846/80965)? I got a little confused by the notation.

To get the differentiation formulas, I did pretty much the same as above, but with $f'(z_o)$:

$$f'(\gamma(\theta))=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{f(\gamma(\theta))}{(\gamma(\theta)-z_o)^2}\gamma'(\theta)\ d\theta=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}f(re^{i\theta}+z_o)(re^{i\theta})^{-1}\ d\theta \tag{1}$$

**(b)**: Is there a way to get something *prettier looking* like: 
$$f'(z_o)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}f(e^{i\theta}+z_o)(e^{i\theta})^{-1}\ d\theta \tag{2}$$

In $(2)$ I feel that we are only moving the argument.

Comment: can't we just make substitution in Cauchy Integral formula?

Comment: @SantoshLinkha That's what I thought, but I can't find a way to get rid of the $r$

Comment: take $r=1$, a unit circle, it will still include only the singularity since $f(z)$ is assumed to be analytic.

Comment: @SantoshLinkha but what if the unit circle is _too_ big for $\Gamma$? can't that happen?

Comment: it shouldn't make difference unless $f(z)$ has pole outside of region $\Gamma$

Comment: @SantoshLinkha uhm... so if we had as hypothesis that $f$ is analytic in and over $\Gamma$ then we're save. What if that doesn't happen? What can we do?

Comment: perhaps you wouldn't get this nice formula, I mean you cannot freely manipulate the values of $r$. I have't experimented with it, but in many cases, usually $f$ is nice we can evaluate integrals like
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \log (a + b \sin (x)) dx$$

Comment: here is an [example](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/801136/find-the-value-of-the-integral-int-02-pi-lnab-sin-xdx-where-0-lt-a-lt) i had difficulty dealing with it, but IDK how integral happened to be real part of it.

Comment: @SantoshLinkha wow, that was intense...

Comment: haha ... i suppose no $f(z)$ has to be analytic in region $|z-z_0| < 1$ from [here](http://planetmath.org/gaussmeanvaluetheorem) since what you claim in just higher order generalization. still let's see what experts has to say ,,, I am just small fry on Complex Analysis.